# Adding multiple constraints in ORACLE using ALTER TABLE

Tags: oracle, constraints

Is there a way to add multiple constraints in Oracle at once using the `ALTER TABLE` command? I know it is possible with SQL server.

```
ALTER TABLE l_customer_order 
    ADD CONSTRAINT pk_l_customer_order 
        PRIMARY KEY (customer_order_id_hk),
    CONSTRAINT fk_customer_id_hk 
        FOREIGN KEY (customer_id_hk) 
        REFERENCES h_customers(customer_id_hk)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_order_id_hk 
        FOREIGN KEY (order_id_hk) 
        REFERENCES h_orders(order_id_hk)
        ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Error message:

```
Error report -
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: That's simply not possible in Oracle

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Place the constraints in parentheses:

```
create table t (
  c1 int, c2 int, c3 int
);

alter table t
  add ( 
    constraint pk 
      primary key ( c1 ),
    constraint ck 
      check ( c2 > 0 )
  );

select constraint_name 
from   user_constraints
where  table_name = 'T';

CONSTRAINT_NAME   
CK                 
PK
```